# ASP.NET DateTime format in Initializer

Tags: asp.net

I'am new in ASP.NET and I have a little question...  For my project I have a class called "Period" wich has as StartDate and a EndDate.  Both are DateTimes.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime startDatum { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime eindDatum { get; set; }
```

I also have an Initializer class for some dummy data.  How do I define the date format ?
I have tried '25/03/2016', "25/03/2016" , ('25/03/2016'), .... but none if these are accepted.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. What you specified is the display format. If you want to generate a date from a string, you need to *parse* it with the DateTime.Parse or ParseExact, specifying the format of the string. You can avoid the format string if you pass the text in the ISO 8601 format (full date+time) or the unseparated format (eg `20160201`)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Now I know how to continue.